# How to select a column to appear with two single quote in the field

Tags: postgresql, single-quotes

Here is my postgresql query

```
select 'insert into employee(ID_NUMBER,NAME,OFFICE) values ('''||ID_NUMBER||''','''||NAME||''','''||replace(DESIGNATION,'&','and')||''','''||replace(DEPT_NAME,'&','and')||''')' as col 
from icare_employee_view 
where id_number='201403241' 
order by name;
```

output

```
insert into employee(ID_NUMBER,NAME,OFFICE) values ('201403241','ABINUMAN, JOSEPHINE CALLO','Assistant AGrS Principal for Curriculum and Instruction','AGrS Principal's Office')
```

but I need `'AGrS Principal's Office'` to be `'AGrS Principal''s Office'`

but I need 'AGrS Principal's Office' to be 'AGrS Principal''s Office'

any suggestions or sol'n is highly appreciated on how to fix my PostgreSQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi check this from [pgDocs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

> quote_literal ( text ) → text
>
> Returns the given string suitably quoted to be used as a string
> literal in an SQL statement string. Embedded single-quotes and
> backslashes are properly doubled. Note that quote_literal returns null
> on null input; if the argument might be null, quote_nullable is often
> more suitable. See also Example 43.1.
>
> quote_literal(E'O'Reilly') → 'O''Reilly'